# I can't use elipsis in the flex box, what should I do?

Tags: flexbox

I can't use elipsis in the flex box, what should I do?
I don't think the width works in the variable area.
Text ellipsis in Flexbox not working :(
Please help me improve my source code.

```
<style>
  .container {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .list.left {
    flex: 0 0 300px;
  }
  .list.right {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .row p {
    flex: 1;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .row button {
    width: 50px;
  }
</style>
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="list left">
    <div class="row">
      <p>abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde</p>
      <button>edit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list right">
    <div class="row">
      <p>abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde</p>
      <button>edit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it's working fine. Is there any issue still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `display: flex; flex-direction: row` on container.

```css
.container {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .list.left {
    flex: 0 0 300px;
  }
  .list.right {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .row p {
    flex: 1;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .row button {
    width: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list left">
    <div class="row">
      <p>abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde</p>
      <button>edit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list right">
    <div class="row">
      <p>abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde</p>
      <button>edit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```